# influxdb query with flux fails

Tags: influxdb

I try the following query to get data from the influxdb with flux syntax. Normal queries with the old syntax are working and with the CLi I can also query.

```
 curl -XPOST localhost:8086/api/v2/query -sS -H 'Accept:application/csv' -H 'Content-type:application/vnd.flux' -d 'from(bucket: "TvssDataContainer")'
```

I get the error:
"type error 1:14-1:31: undefined identifier ""TvssDataContainer"""
What is wrong?

If I query buckets like:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:8086/api/v2/query?db=TvssDataContainer -sS -H 'Accept:application/csv' -H 'Content-type:application/vnd.flux' -d 'buckets()'
```

I get:

```
#datatype,string,long,string,string,string,string,long
#group,false,false,false,false,true,false,false
#default,_result,,,,,,
,result,table,name,id,organizationID,retentionPolicy,retentionPeriod
,,0,_internal/monitor,,,monitor,604800000000000
,,0,TvssDataContainer/autogen,,,autogen,0
```

Answer (score 0):

In Flux, a `bucket` includes the retention policy, so try using `from(bucket: "TvssDataContainer/autogen")` instead